# how to detect links in a string using RegEx in as3?

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3, string

I am trying to find the generic links in strings. I've found a very handy regex on [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/), in the community expressions:

```
(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?(:\d{1,5})?
```

I tried to use it and it returns null, although the same string tested on RegExr works fine:

```
var linkRegEx:RegExp = new RegExp("(https?://)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\b\.[a-z]{2,4}(\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\.[a-z]*)?(:\d{1,5})?","g");
var link:String = 'generic links: www.google.com http://www.google.com  google.com';
trace(linkRegEx.exec(link));//traces null
```

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to double the backslashes when you're using new RegExp.  you might want to use the literal syntax, which doesn't impose such a requirement (assuming AS3 admits this syntax, I just know JS.

Comment: Yes, AS3 allows literal RegExp syntax.

Comment: backslashes fixed it. Thanks! That was quick!

Comment: in case anyone else might be interested, I updated: "var linkRegEx:RegExp = new RegExp("(https?://)?(www\\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\\b\\.[a-z]{2,4}(\\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\\.[a-z]*)?(:\\d{1,5})?","g");"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you're trying to match the wrong variable? In line `linkRegEx.exec(formattedStatus)`, `formattedStatus` isn't defined.